# RubyMotion and CocoaPods problems

Tags: cocoapods, rubymotion

I'm various issues getting CocoaPods dependencies to work in RubyMotion. Firstly, if I add `dependency 'JSONKit'` to my Rakefile and then run `rake` it get's aborted with a `can't convert Pathname into String` error. `rake --trace` then produces the following output:

```
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke simulator (first_time)
** Invoke build:simulator (first_time)
** Execute build:simulator
/usr/bin/gen_bridge_metadata --format complete --no-64-bit --cflags "-I. -I." JSONKit.h -o "JSONKit.bridgesupport"
invalid option: --no-64-bit
Usage: gen_bridge_metadata [options] <headers...>
Use the `-h' flag or consult gen_bridge_metadata(1) for help.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/gen_bridge_metadata --format comp...]
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:93:in `block in build_static'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:34:in `chdir'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:34:in `build_static'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb:23:in `build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:37:in `block in build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:36:in `each'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:36:in `build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/app.rb:50:in `build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => default => simulator => build:simulator
```

The vendor directory in the project contains various JSONKit files.

Secondly, in another RubyMotion app, if I add `dependency 'Nimbus'` to my Rakefile and then run `rake` the app builds but errors out with uninitialized constant errors when I try to use anything Nimbus-related in my code and no vendor directory is created.

What is the problem in these two instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple issues at play here.

**can't convert Pathname into String**

**Update: As of 5/7/12, you can just `sudo motion update` and this will be fixed**

This error has to do with the fact that you're using Ruby 1.9. Though I don't see it explicitly stated in the documentation, the fact that the examples of setting this up refer to using `sudo` in the `gem install` commands means it's assumed you're running OS X's built-in ruby (1.8.7). If you switch your project to system ruby (add a `.rbenv-version` file with `system` in it). Alternatively, if you want to stick with 1.9, you can change line 22 of `/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb` to read:

```
App.info 'Build', @path.to_s
```

Once doing this, there's a good chance you'll then get an error like this:

```
ERROR! Building vendor project `./vendor/JSONKit' failed to create at least one `.a' library.`
```

You'll need to edit line 77 of that same file to read:

```
objs = Dir.glob('**/*.o') # Removed the leading "*/"
```

Then `rake` should finally work properly.

An issue has been filed on the `motion-cocoapods` repo regarding these issues: https://github.com/HipByte/motion-cocoapods/issues/1

Additionally, I just filed an official support ticket for this using `motion support`. (Remember, you paid money for this brand new product which includes support; use it!)

**Nimbus**

The problem here is that you're requiring the top-level cocoapod. Since it has "subspecs", you need to require those directly, so maybe `dependency 'Nimbus/Core'` instead. You can see a full list of them [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Nimbus/0.9.2/Nimbus.podspec) (see the `s.subspec` entries)

Comment: Thanks Dylan. I tried bypassing rbenv like you suggested but it led to another error (https://gist.github.com/fa676e1f52349067d49e). So instead I edited vendor.rb as you said but that still leaves me with the `invalid option: --no-64-bit` error as mentioned below by shawn42. The Nimbus solution was dead on, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I didn't run into the 64-bit error on my machine, but it sounds like shawn42's answer below should help with that.

Comment: Also, thanks for filing the support ticket. I did so myself on Friday night but I hadn't received any response - guessing that the guys at HipByte are pretty busy right now!

Comment: RubyMotion 1.2, just released, fixes the issues relating to the `vendor.rb` file.

Answer (score 1):

The compilation error about the --no-64-bit flag is because of a but on RubyMotion on Snow Leopard. update /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/vendor.rb per https://gist.github.com/2597428

The bug has been confirmed by Laurent Sansonetti:

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for the report! The problem is that the --no-64-bit flag was
>   added in Lion and you appear to be running Snow Leopard. We will get
>   this fixed.
>
> Laurent

Comment: Thanks shawn42. I am indeed running Snow Leopard. Your change from the gist plus Dylan's change to line 77 of vendor.rb (mentioned above) fixed the `--no-64-bit` errors.